# How to display Object Details by a reference via a TapGestureRecognizer within a ListView in Xamarin Forms MVVM

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView displaying multiple cases, and I would like to display its page details when I click on the the Reference from the list.  I only get a blank page.

I have tried EventHandler from my XAML and did not work.

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GetCases}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0">
                                    <Label Text="Case Reference:" FontSize="14" TextColor="Green"/>
                                    <Label FontSize="12" TextColor="Blue" FontAttributes="Bold">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding Reference}" TextColor="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline">   // I can get the list of References here, but can go to their details
                                                    <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.GoToPageDetails, Source={x:Reference Page}}" />    //This approach takes me to the Page Details, but it is blank
                                                    </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </Span>
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

VIEWMODEL

```
 public CasesViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        IGetDataFromServer cases = new GetDataFromServer();
        Navigation = navigation;
        GoToPageDetails = new Command(async () => await PageDetails());
        GetCases = cases.GetCases();     // This code retrieves my data from server - it Works fine       
    }
```

public Command GoToPageDetails { get; set; }

```
    public async Task PageDetails()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new CaseDetails());
    }
```

CASE DETAILS XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GetCases}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0">
                                    <Label Text="PERSONAL DETAILS" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
                                    <Label Text="Status:" FontSize="14" TextColor="Green"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding status}" 
                                FontSize="12" TextColor="Black" />
                            </StackLayout>
                          </ViewCell.View>
                      </ViewCell>
                  </ DataTemplate>
               </ ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ ListView>
```

CASE DETAILS VIEWMODEL

```
 public CaseDetailsViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        IGetDataFromServer cases = new GetDataFromServer();
        Navigation = navigation;
        GetCases = cases.GetCases().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public CasesFull GetCases { get; set; }
```

I can navigate to Case Details page, but it is blank.  Maybe I am not passing the reference to the page, or maybe it is something else.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you set the bindingContext of the DetailsPage ? If the page is sucessfully pushed but you got blank, check if the `{Binding GetCases}` is working, cause this means the reference to the page is working for binding. Plus, I see that you are doing a `cases.GetCases().FirstOrDefault` , which means you will only have one object for your listView. Is that the behavior you want to have ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem.
The issue was in my Case Details View Model, as I had to add the Model in all properties of the Cases Details View model (see below).

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GetCases}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0">
                                <Label Text="PERSONAL DETAILS" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
                                <Label Text="Status:" FontSize="14" TextColor="Green"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Case.status}" 
                            FontSize="12" TextColor="Black" />
                        </StackLayout>
                      </ViewCell.View>
                  </ViewCell>
              </ DataTemplate>
           </ ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Where Case is my Model.
If anyone wants to display details of an object, this code can be your solution.
Thanks  **Umar3x** for your help.